# What is Breaking this deluxetable.sty file?

Tags: texlive, aastex

Astronomers use the deluxetable environment provided by [AASTeX](http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex.html). For those seeking to use deluxetables without AASTeX, in a thesis, for example, [AAS links to a deluxetable.sty](https://aas.org/faq/there-separate-deluxetable-style-file-i-can-use-outside-aastex) file to make this possible. I'm getting an error when I try to use deluxetable.sty with TeXLive (both 2015 and 2016) that suggests it depends on a feature that was deprecated and removed at some point. The error reads:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Article.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(./deluxetable.sty) (./Article.aux)
./Article.tex:16: Undefined control sequence.
\@halignto ->\@to 
                  \pt@width 
l.16    \startdata

?
```

The only lines from deluxetable.sty that this could refer to are:

```
\let\typeout@deluxetable\typeout@deluxetable@mss 
\newcommand\startdata{% 
 \pt@calcnlines 
 \@ifdim{\pt@width>\z@}{% 
  \def\@halignto{\@to\pt@width}% 
 }{% 
  \def\@halignto{}% 
 }% 
 \let\fnum@table=\fnum@ptable 
 \let\@makecaption\@makecaption@plano 
 \global\pt@line\z@ 
 \start@pt@tabular 
 \after@startdata 
}
```

Anyone know what is breaking this file, and how to fix it? Here is a simple article that should work, but gives the compile error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\documentclass{aastex6}
\usepackage{deluxetable}

\begin{document}

\title{Make Slack Work for You}
\author{Bob Dobbs}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{deluxetable}{lcc}
    \tablewidth{0.72\textwidth}
    \tablecaption{Putting Things in Tables Makes Them True}
    \tablehead{ \colhead{A Column} & \colhead{Another Column}  & \colhead{The Third Column}  }
    \startdata
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f
    \enddata
    \tablecomments{Believe the Table!}
    \label{mySpiffyTable}
\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue yesterday (with another template that used to work fine), I also got the error "undefined controlsequence". Try adding `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` before `\documentclass` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @blue_tiger300. I tried it and got the same error.

Comment: I have published in `A&A` (years) ago, but I did not encounter `deluxetable` (and many of co-workers at that time too), so stating `astronomers` use `deluxetable` is very ... bold ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The undefined command is `\@to`, which probably was defined in some older version of the `aastex` class.

Note that `deluxetable` is defined in quite a different way in `deluxetable.sty` and in `aastex6.cls`.

You can solve the issue in two ways.

### First way

Add a proper definition for `\@to`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{deluxetable}

\makeatletter
\def\@to{to}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Make Slack Work for You}
\author{Bob Dobbs}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{deluxetable}{lcc}
    \tablewidth{0.72\textwidth}
    \tablecaption{Putting Things in Tables Makes Them True}
    \tablehead{ \colhead{A Column} & \colhead{Another Column}  & \colhead{The Third Column}  }
    \startdata
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f
    \enddata
    \tablecomments{Believe the Table!}
    \label{mySpiffyTable}
\end{deluxetable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Second way (preferred)

Forget about `deluxetable`, which does nothing really useful or pretty. For table notes you can use the `threeparttable` package.

Comment: Excellent! I was able to edit the deluxetable.sty file and it compiles fine now. While I understand your point about using the threeparttable package, this is a question of backward compatibility with an existing code base, so I'm going with the deluxetable solution. There may be some edge cases where deluxetable.sty differs in behavior for aastex6's deluxetable, but I can face those when the crop up.